# Equivalent definitions to $D_{n}$

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, definition, dihedral-groups

I am looking for equivalent definitions for $D_{n}$.

I have this: The Dihedral group of degree $2n$ ($D_{n}$) is the group of symmetries of a regular polygon of $n$ sides. But, when I am trying to work with it, this definition is not much useful.

I saw a definition of it using two elements $a$ and $b$ of order $n$ and $2$, respectively. Can someone explain this construction in detail, and how I can prove that those definitions are equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One definition is that $D_n$ of order $2n$ is the group given by the [presentation](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Presentation_of_a_group)

$$\langle a,b\mid a^2, b^n, ab=b^{-1}a\rangle.$$

Here $a$ corresponds to a flip of an $n$-gon, whereas $b$ is a rotation by $\frac{2\pi}{n}$.

Comment: Yes! That is what i saw. But, How I can arrive to this beggining with my actual definition?

Comment: I've added a little extra, @JohnMars. Is that sufficient?

Comment: Oh, I see. Maybe, must I compare the group-tables of both using your new information?

Comment: @JohnMars if you show the flip and rotation in your $n$-gon description ($H$) obey those relations that $a$ and $b$ obey in the presentation ($G$), and if you declare that the symmetries of the regular $n$-gon are generated by a flip and a rotation, then this is enough to tell you $H$ is a quotient of $G$. You can determine they're isomorphic then by noting they have the same size.

Comment: Why the downvote?